# R2DBC support in Jooq for Reactive applications

Tags: java, sql, jooq, r2dbc

Currently I have written my project using spring boot + hikari connection pool, and fetching the result using fetchAsync method.
But according to this documentation [Reactive fetching](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/fetching/reactive-fetching/), its Blocking JDBC API.

Is it possible to encapsulate CompletionStage object of fetchAsync method with flux and make it reactive ?

Is there a plan for supporting r2dbc with connnection pool, and timeline if underway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ will support R2DBC in the upcoming 3.15 version:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11700

Comment: what about encapsulation of CompletionStage object with flux ? is that possible ?

Comment: That's possible but wouldn't make it reactive.